# Can I assign a variable to check multiple arrays inside a loop?

Tags: javascript, arrays, variables

I am trying to check through multiple arrays inside of a loop, all with the same index. Instead of manually coding through every list I wanted to soft code it so every time the function loops it can check through all of my arrays. All of my arrays are named: score1-score8, but whenever this code runs it doesn't actually check any of the lists.

```
function checkHorizontal()
{

    var rowcount=0;
    var checkLists;
    var player1=0;
    var player2=0;

    checkLists="score"+rowcount;

    for (var i = 0; rowcount <= 8; i++) 
    {
        rowcount+=1;
        if(checkLists[rowcount]==1) 
        {
            player1+=1;
            player2=0;    
        }
        else if (checkLists[rowcount]==2)
        {
            player2+=1;
            player1=0;
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Use `window["score" + rowcount]`

Comment: what is a window I dont think I have ever used that before, I'm kind of new to coding if you cant already tell

Answer (score 0):

Instead of giving each score a variable name that has an index, you can save the scores in an array and use another `for` loop.

Here's an example, assuming:

- We have two players
- A game consists of an unknown number of sets
- A set consists of an unknown number of legs

```js
const player1 = 1;
const player2 = 2;

const set1 = [ 1, 2, 1 ];
const set2 = [ 1, 2, 2 ];
const set3 = [ 2, 2, 1 ];

let player1Score = 0;
let player2Score = 1;

// Create a new array containing all sets:
const game = [ set1, set2, set3 ];

// Loop over every set in the game
for (let s = 0; s < game.length; s += 1) {
  const set = game[s];
  
  // Loop over the legs in every set
  for (let g = 0; g < set.length; g += 1) {
    const winner = set[g];
    
    if (winner === player1) player1Score += 1;
    if (winner === player2) player2Score += 1;
  }
}

console.log(`The final match score is player1 ${player1Score} vs player2 ${player2Score}`);
```

For your specific case, you could define `game` as `[ score1, score2, score3, score4, score5, score6, score7, score8 ]`

If the number of players can also differ, you could add them to an array as well! You'd get a *third* loop, checking to which player you need to assign a point for every leg you process.